# Visual Studio 2015 Community can't create a Windows Phone 8.1 application

Tags: windows-10-mobile, windows-8, windows-mobile

Guys I am new to windows phone development although I am an Android Developer. 
I am trying to get started with the Windows phone Development. 
I have installed Visual studio 2015 community. I build-ed a universal application from all the video tutorials and blogs but I can't see any Windows phone 8.1 emulators and also the windows phone 8.1 template in creating project 
[image]

[image]

I want to build an app for windows phone which can run on Windows phone 10,8.1 and windows 8.0 with Visual Studio 2015 Community

Comment: Did you try Windows 8 -> Universal?

Comment: have you selected the W81 tools during VS2015 setup?

Comment: earlier i did not selected WP8.1 option while running the setup..
i re-run the setup and selected WP8.1 now everything is perfect

Comment: ok nice to hear this. I posted it as answer.

Comment: can you suggest me a book for windows phone 8 or 8.1 development

Comment: next time, please use @myusername so that I see your reply. Watch this video series: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Visual Studio 2015 doesn't install the 8.1 Store development tools. In Setup click on `custom`

[image]

and here select the Windows 8.1 / Phone 8.1 Tools:

[image]

[image]

If you also want the 8.1 Emulators, select the Emulators.